# Prove that for any monic polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients, if $q$ is a (complex) root of $f$ and $p$ is a prime, then $f(q^p) = 0 \pmod p.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any monic polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients, if $q$ is a (complex) root of $f$ and $p$ is a prime, then $f(q^p) = 0 \pmod p.$

Can you provide a simple proof?

Answer (score 4):

The complexness of the root in question has nothing to do with the case.

There’s a problem with the innocent-looking statement $f(q^p)\equiv0\pmod p$. That means that the quantity $f(q^p)$ is supposed to be a multiple of $p$. Within what ring? Certainly not within $\Bbb Q(q)$, since that’s a field, and every element of a field of characteristic zero is a multiple of $p$. You have to assume that “$f(q^p)\equiv0\pmod p$” means that $f(q^p)$ is a multiple of $p$ in some significant smaller ring. Let’s say it has to be $p$ times an element of the ring $\Bbb Z(q)$, which is a ring of algebraic integers, because $q$ is an algebraic integer. With that understanding, we can proceed.

Using the Binomial Theorem, you see that for integers $a$ and $b$, $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p\pmod p$. If $f(X)\in\Bbb Z[X]$, then applying the above to the coefficients of $f$,  you see that $\bigl(f(X)\bigr)^p=f(X^p)+pg(X)$, for an appropriate polynomial $g\in\Bbb Z[X]$. Now assume that $f$ is monic, and plug in your root $q$ of $f$ to the equation, giving $f(q^p)=(f(q))^p-pg(q)=-pg(q)\in p\Bbb Z[q]$, as desired.